# Specifying conditions on database results to array

Tags: php, arrays

In my database I have a field called "modules" - info data looks like this:  1, 4, 1, 3
I want to list/output all data via PHP with the numbers 1 - all other numbers have to be ignored.

**I want to check the output result via an array NOT via mySQL**

Any suggestion how I can do that?

```
$list_modules = array();
            $res_m = $db->Execute("SELECT modules FROM users u WHERE user_id = '".$user->id."'");
            while ( $m = $res_m->GetNext() ) {
                $list_modules = array($m['modules']);
            }

            print_r($list_modules); //Output below
```

Example (Output):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1, 4, 1, 3
)
```

Comment: @Lars: Yes modules is a varchar

Comment: Which database? MySQL supports the RLIKE comparator which might be useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh found the solution I could use.

```
$list_modules = array();
            $query = "SELECT modules FROM users WHERE user_id = ".$user->id."";
            $res_m = $db->Execute($query);
            while ( $m = $res_m->GetNext() ) {
                $list_modules = array('id' => $m['modules']);
            }

$modules = explode(",",$list_modules['id']);
            foreach ($modules as $key => $value) {

                if($value == 1){
                // list data    
                   }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in you MySQL with a `WHERE` clause.  Depending on the column name in the database:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE column_name = 1;
```

Note: In your question it looks like you tried to list a range:

> with the numbers 1 - all other numbers have to be ignored.

If you meant to put a *range* (e.g. 1 - 4) then your WHERE clause would be:

```
WHERE column_name BETWEEN 1 AND 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You should test for that in your MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `modules` = 1;
```

Or, alternatively, if that's not possible..

Loop with foreach and test for 1?

```
$array = array(1,4,1,3);
foreach ($array as $element) {
    if ($element == 1) { echo 1; }
}
```

Comment: @william probably wants to do this on the MYSQL level.

Comment: You mean he should do it on the MySQL level. That's not always possible.

Comment: My DB field: modules is comma separated (1, 4, 1, 3) - So I can't use the WHERE `modules` = 1;

Comment: Please show an example output from your table. 3-4 rows should do. @william

Comment: I don't know if my example is useful. Maybe I could combine the foreach above, I just don't know how to ignore the other numbers that 1.

Comment: @william what do you want the output to look like? 1, 1?

Answer (score 0):

You stated in your comment that the `modules` field contains comma-separated values, is that right? I reckon that the `modules` field is `VARCHAR`, `CHAR`, or any other string. If so, you could use a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE `modules` LIKE '%1,%';
```

There may be other solutions, probably more optimal, but this one should perform well, I think.

Comment: That's going to grab 1, 11, 111, 21, and so on.

Comment: That's right. Should be okay now, I corrected the query to look for the comma, too.

Comment: If 1 is last it won't find it now. That will match `21,9` but not `3,1`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it... there is really no other way seeing at the col is Varchar, you also need to eliminate strings like 15, 21, etc. so %1% will not work.

```
SELECT modules FROM users WHERE user_id = ".$user->id." AND modules LIKE % 1,%
```

Give it a shot and let me know if it works.

Comment: Always escape your SQL. It's reckless to skip this step.

Comment: Thanks... I should never assume... Make sure to escape your SQL